# Deletar um intervalo de valores no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um código que elimina valores conforme necessário, mas não estou conseguindo colocar um intervalo para deletar ou ficar com o valor. Por exemplo, quero valores entre às 19 e 5 horas.

Se colocar valores maiores que 18h, ele aceita, mas não as duas condições ao mesmo tempo. Segue o código:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/boia_deriva/B116353_col_2018.csv')

type(dataset)

df = pd.concat([dataset], ignore_index=True)
df = dataset.loc[(dataset[' hour'] > 18) &  (dataset[' hour'] < 6)]
df.to_csv('/home/Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/boia_deriva/B116353_col_2018_noite.csv')
```

Alguém sabe como corrigir?

P.S.: sei que no caso coloquei o símbolo `&`, e no caso seria `OR`, mas o mesmo não aceita, fala que:

> 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua lógica está invertida, or conta de como expressamos os problemas de forma coloquial em português.

Se você diz de forma programática - como está acima, que quer apenas os valores maiores que 18 **e** e os valores menores que 6, o resultado é nenhum valor, por que nenhum número pode ser ao mesmo tempo maior que 18 e menor que 6.

Você precisa de uma condição "ou" - e, no mundo de Numpy + Pandas (que exige uma forma um pouco diferente de pensar do que usar Python sem usar essas bibliotecas), isso é feito com o operador `|` (e não com o operador `&`). Em código Python sem envolver ações vetorizadas por Numpy sim, se usaria o operador `or` por extenso.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/boia_deriva/B116353_col_2018.csv')

type(dataset)

df = pd.concat([dataset], ignore_index=True)
df = dataset.loc[(dataset[' hour'] > 18) | (dataset[' hour'] < 6)]
df.to_csv('/home/Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/boia_deriva/B116353_col_2018_noite.csv')
```